# Android: DetailActivity with View and Edit Fragment - how to start it

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, view, fragment

I am currently trying to implement a ListActivity and a DetailActivity with a DetailFragment. When clicking an item in the list the DetailActivity with its fragment is created and displayed.

Now I want to extend this to have this "viewing" fragment where you see read-only data and a new fragment where you can edit this detail data.
I already achieved this by using the FragmentManager to replace the view fragment with the edit fragment.

Want I now need is the following: When I am in the ListActivity I want to click on an "Add" button in the menu and it should bring me directly to the "Edit" fragment instead of the "View" fragment, which is currently the default.

I tried the following but I am pretty unsure if this is the right way:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sunit_detail);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
        if (uri != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_sunit_detail, new SUnitDetailActivityFragment()).commit();
       }
    else {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_sunit_detail, new SUnitDetailEditFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

I pass a URI from the ListActivity to the DetailActivity but when Adding a new item this is empty. But still this does not work as expected...

Any help or hint would be great ;-)

Comment: I think I found a solution, it is working now. Problem was a little bit different as replacing the fragments with each other overlays the first. I had to change the xml of the DetailActivity, which contained a <fragment /> to <FrameLayout /> and afterwards loading and replacing via FragmentManager worked!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution, it is working now. Problem was a little bit different as replacing the fragments with each other overlays the first.

I had to change the xml of the DetailActivity, which contained a  to  and afterwards loading and replacing via FragmentManager worked!